# 2 differences between blender object and exported FBX file (in unity)

Tags: unity, blend-files

I made a race track part with blender.

[image: Blender render]

This is Unity view
[image: Unity view]

I have two different problems.

1. As you can see some parts of race track is missing in Unity.
2. Color is different in Unity. I changed Filter Mode as *Point*, but I believe that I must change *Non-Power of 2* value, but it's grayed out.

Comment: Is some face normal flipped in your model ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the difference is in lightning. If you match light in Unity and blender colors should be identical.